# How to choose between the lower value of a where condition in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

This one is hard to explain but basically I want pick the condition that has the smaller distance. The query is the following:

```
update point_a a
set c_id = (select b.otherid
from point_b b, line c
where a.pointid = c.lineconnecting_a_id 
and (st_endpoint(c.geom) = b.geom or st_startpoint(c.geom) = b.geom order by distance limit 1
```

Basically on the last line I want to use the line to pick the point in which it connects to and I want the point that's closer to the origin point. Problem is that with my OR, I'm getting 2 points and I don't know how to limit to be able to use st_distance and pick the one closest.

In other words, for each row I need to pick the startpoint or endpoint depending on their distance to the origin point

Comment: Your query is not complete, there's no end for two `(`. Also, your question would be more clear if you add some test data for anyone who would like to test the query to find out what you need.

Comment: Might worth the try `ORDER BY ST_Distance(c.goem, b.goem) LIMIT 1`

Comment: @Dan It's not complete because I trimmed out the "useless" parts

Comment: @RaymondNijland ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list

Comment: @Luffydude when you have distinct on items, you need to order FIRST by the fields by which DISTINCT is done.

Comment: I dont understand your condition. I *think* you want st_distance(), and/or st_within(). Also: the `line c` table is a bridge-table, the actual assignment is `point_a <<-- point_b`, given the existence of *some* row in line_c.

Comment: @joop yes it was st_distamnce. With that basically i wanted to pick which one of the end or start point was closer

Answer (score 1):

Please post valid queries. And table definitions. This might also make it easier to understand your problem

Anyway, if I understood your problem correctly, this should work (untested)

```
update point_a a
set c_id = (

  select  otherid
  from (
    select b.otherid, distance
    from point_b b, line c
    where a.pointid = c.lineconnecting_a_id 
    and (st_endpoint(c.geom) = b.geom)
   UNION
    select b.otherid, distance
    from point_b b, line c
    where a.pointid = c.lineconnecting_a_id 
    and (st_startpoint(c.geom) = b.geom)
  )
  order by distance limit 1
);
```

Comment: I can't post the right query if I don't know how, that's why I'm asking here As for columns, the only ones needed are id, lineconnecting and geom. Your query was missing the alias, and then it's still missing a from on the end. after i removed st_distance on the ordey by, I got ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list

Comment: Note, I edited the answer, but there still seems to be a `)` missing (and a `;` )

Comment: @joop just saw this now, it's missing an alias before the order though. Testing it out

Comment: A scalar subquery doesn't need an alias. And the `);` should go *after* the `limit 1`

Comment: @joop that's odd, on my screen it returned an error saying it needed the alias. I had to cancel the query because it was taking over 4 hours but will see over the weekend

Comment: You say that the only columns needed are id, lineconnecting and geom. The query in your problem statement  has columns "c_id", "pointid", "otherid", "lineconnecting_a_id", "distance" as well (and a couple of functions).

Please post your (stripped down) table definitions if you want my help. Sample data and expected outcome would also be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the `distance`, but IMO this is more or less whatyou want.

---

```
UPDATE point_a a
SET c_id = sub.id
FROM (SELECT b.otherid AS id
        , c.lineconnecting_a_id AS line_id
        FROM point_b b 
        JOIN line c ON st_endpoint(c.geom) = b.geom or st_startpoint(c.geom) = b.geom 
        ORDER BY st_distance (c.geom, b.geom)
        limit 1
        )sub
WHERE a.pointid = sub.line_id            
        ;
```